# confused about indexOf(array[0])

Tags: javascript

This is for a coderbyte challenge that I finished a while ago. Your function is supposed to get the second greatest and second lowest numbers heres what I originally used:

```
function SecondGreatLow(arr){
  var sorted = arr.sort(function(a,b){
  return a-b;
  });
  return sorted[1] + " " + sorted[arr.length - 2];
}
SecondGreatLow(readline());
```

I got two cases wrong with this function one of them being ([2,2,2,5,5,5,6]) because there are duplicate numbers. I implemented this into my new code :

```
function SecondGreatLow(arr) { 
  var exclude = [arr[0]];
  for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (exclude.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) {
      exclude.push(arr[i]);
  }
    }
  return exclude
}
SecondGreatLow([33,33,33,44,44,44,55,55,6,4,3])
```

My question is how does this find all the duplicate numbers? Isn't the variable exclude(arr[0]) 33? I'm confused how this gets rid of all the duplicate numbers.

Comment: I'm confused too. I don't see where `unique` is defined. The code should throw a `ReferenceError`.

Comment: oops sorry edited it I had an old variable name in there should make sense now

Comment: OK, so I assume the function name is now wrong. The function returns the unique array values, not the second highest and second lowest value. Correct?

Comment: Yeah I needed to elaborate a bit more on that the reason I just have return exclude on there is to show that it returns the case for SecondGreatLow with no duplicate numbers. My question is how does it do this if exclude originally is only arr[0] or 33

Comment: You're basically doing this: for each value in arr, check if it is in exclude, if it isn't then append it to exclude. So you get an array of unique numbers. I don't think you even need to assign exclude with the initial value of [arr[0]], just start your loop with i=0.

Comment: exclude.push(someNumber) adds that number to your exclude array. You can now pass your exclude array (containing unique elements) to your function listed earlier (the first one)

Comment: Right I get that so far but how does exclude match to other numbers that aren't the first one from my understanding the numbers in exclude are only 33 since that is the value of arr[0]. Theres something I'm not understanding here.

Comment: You check every number if it is already present in exclude or not... the indexOf method returns -1 if it is not present SO FAR. If that check is true, you keep on adding and UPDATING your exclude array with the help of push.

Comment: `exclude.indexOf(44) == -1` is `true` because `44` is not in `exclude`. It is then added to `exclude`, so that its value becomes `[33, 44]`. Maybe you just don't know what `indexOf` does? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My question is how does this find all the duplicate numbers?

It actually doesn't find duplicate values, it collects unique values.

You iterate over the original array and add only values to `exclude` which are not already in `exclude`. That guarantees that every value in `exclude` is unique.

> My question is how does it do this if exclude originally is only arr[0] or 33

This line:

```
var exclude = [arr[0]];
```

it just used to not start with an empty array. As you can see in the `for` statement

```
for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

the code starts iterating at index `1`, not `0`. You could also just have started with an empty array:

```
var exclude = [];
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
```

but that's a bit wasteful since you know that the first value is going to be added to `exclude` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The way this code works is but adding new variables into the array exclude. It will only add the new variable if the current variable doesn't already exist in the array exclude. 
The line:

```
exclude.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1
```

is what is doing main work. 
It finds variable i and check if it already exists in the array exclude. If it does not exist indexOf returns -1, thus the if statement is true, and we go into the line

```
exclude.push(arr[i]);
```

and add the variable into the array exclude.

Answer (score 0):

In the below loop

```
for(var i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (exclude.indexOf(arr[i]) == -1) {
        exclude.push(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

It is checking if the number from input array is already present in exclude if not it will insert that number to exclude.

The indexOf() method searches the array for the specified item, and returns its position. so in case of duplicate numbers it will not return -1 thus the logic above will skip adding that duplicate number to exculde variable. You can refer below for more details.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof_array.asp